# Parameterizing 'ORDER BY ' in SQL query with ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<T>()

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4

My question is on top of this question:

[Entity Framework and the raw string query - SQL injection prevention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297903/entity-framework-and-the-raw-string-query-sql-injection-prevention).

How to parameterize limit and order by commands in this context?

Thanks a lot.

UPDATE:

I tried this code, but it does not work:

```
var filters = new StringBuilder();
var parameters = new List<object>();


decimal numRealPrice = 25.00m;
filters.Append("RealPrice = @RealPrice");
var paramRealPrice = new SqlParameter("@RealPrice", SqlDbType.Decimal);
paramRealPrice.Value = numRealPrice;
parameters.Add(paramRealPrice);


var paramSort = new SqlParameter("@field", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
paramSort.Value = "Id";
parameters.Add(paramSort);


string sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM gift WHERE ";

sqlStatement = sqlStatement + filters + " ORDER BY @field DESC";
```

The SQL generated is:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM gift WHERE RealPrice = @RealPrice ORDER BY @Id DESC',
N'@RealPrice decimal(4,2), @Id varchar(2)',
@RealPrice=25.00,
@Id='id'

go
```

And the error message is:

> The SELECT item identified by the ORDER BY number 1 contains a
>   variable as part of the expression identifying a column position.
>   Variables are only allowed when ordering by an expression referencing
>   a column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot parameterize the `ORDER BY` clause. Since you are already constructing/composing the query in C#, the most effective approach is going to be to simply white-list that argument and add the clause directly:

```
string orderByField = "Id"; // or whatever

// whitelist the field
switch(orderByField) {
    case "Id":
    case "Name":
    ...
        break; // these are OK
    default:
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Illegal order clause: " + orderByField);
}

sqlStatement = sqlStatement + filters + " ORDER BY " + orderByField + " DESC";
```

Comment: Serious? That looks a little bit awkward. But thanks.

Comment: @VincentZHANG which bit looks awkward?

Comment: Imagine that the query is going to get all the fields from three inner-joined tables (may be 4), and all the fields could be a sorting criteria. As a result, the case list in the switch block will be pretty long.

Comment: @VincentZHANG yes; and? Note: there are ways to simplify that (perhaps having the allowed fields in an array or hash-set somewhere, and just checking `Contains`).

Answer (score 1):

In the exact same way it shows in the answer of that question however you need to change your SQL to have a case statement in it for OrderBy clauses.

```
 SELECT * FROM gift 
    ORDER BY 
    CASE @dir 
        WHEN 'desc' THEN  
        CASE @col 
            WHEN 'id' THEN id
            END 
        END 
        DESC, 
    CASE @dir 
        WHEN 'asc' THEN              
        CASE @field 
            WHEN 'id' THEN id 
            END 
        END
```

Then insert the parameters as

```
var param = new SqlParameter("@field", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
param.Value = name;
parameters.Add(param);
```

Then another one here to determine the direction

```
var param = new SqlParameter("@dir", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
param.Value = 'desc'; // or 'asc'
parameters.Add(param);
```

Comment: Thank you. How about DESC & ASC?

Comment: This approach is *really, really* bad for index usage; it shouldn't be used except for trivial scenarios